# Full name to variable in CMD

Tags: windows, variables, cmd, command-prompt

this should be pretty basic, but I can't figure it out.

I trying to set the full name of the user to a variable to use further in the my batch script.

I thought it should be something like this:

SET VAR=NET USER %username% /DOMAIN | FIND /I "Full name";
echo "%VAR%"

The NET USER %username% /DOMAIN | FIND /I "Full name" works on its own, but not when I try to set it to a variable.

Maybe this is more a general question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary file or [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to achieve this:

**temporary file** solution:

```
NET USER %username% /DOMAIN | FIND /I "Full name" >tmp.txt
set /p VAR=<tmp.txt
echo %VAR%
del tmp.txt
```

**for /f** solution:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('NET USER %username% /DOMAIN ^| FIND /I "Full name"') do set VAR=%i
```

Note:

- Replace `%` with `%%` if using the above command in a batch file.
- Use `"tokens=*"` to match *all* of the output from the command
- `^` is used because the `|` (pipe) must be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Comment: You can use `"tokens=2*"` and `set VAR=%j` to store just the name out of a line such as `"Full Name                    John Doe"`.

Comment: For the temp file, you could add a `:mktemp` subroutine such as `SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%.tmp"`  `IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" GOTO :mktemp`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the already specified %username% and %userdomain%.

Type `set` for a list of values.

Type `set /?` for a list of dynamic variables.

Comment: Bjorn wants the user's full name, which is available by parsing the output from `net user`.